# Asp.net 4 Login Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a usermanagement table into my sql server 2008 i want to check each user with their particular role frm my database & not from asp.net predefined database. please help me with the code for the same. also what i need to change into my web config file.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to implement (roll your own) version of the membership provider to make this job easier, more secure and less error prone - it will also save you writing tons of additional plumbing code.

In essence it means implementing the IIdentity and IPrincipal interfaces (Sounds scary but its really not that bad). See this blog here http://www.bradygaster.com/custom-authentication-with-mvc-3.0 for a step by step guide. Additionally it is worth reading the comments and links to enable proper Forms Authentication via Auth Cookie rather than the basic session management referenced directly in the post!.

Also note this example on the blog is for MVC 3 BUT its equally applicable to Web Forms projects too.

Comment: THEN PLEASE GUIDE ME HOW TO SOLVE MY PROBLEM. I HAVE A COMPLETE USER MANAGEMENT TABLE WITH ROLES THEN WHAT TO DO